# Hilbert's Weak Nullstellensatz Variety Ideal

Tags: polynomials, ideals

I have the following question....

$f=6x^2y-xy^2-2y^3+1\ and \ h=3x-2y \in \mathbb{C}[x,y] $

Im asked to Show that V(f,h) is empty.. But im not sure what method I use to show this...

Then im asked.. What can you say about the ideal (f,h)?

Im really stuck on where to even start with this question..

Answer (score 2):

Take zero of $\,h\,\Longrightarrow 3x=2y$ , and substitute in $\,f\,$:

$$6x^2\frac{3x}{2}-x\frac{9x^2}{4}-2\frac{27x^3}{8}+1=0\iff 9x^3-\frac{9x^3}{4}-\frac{27x^3}{4}+1=0\iff 1=0$$

Comment: So to prove it is empty.. I just need to put them equal to zero and show its not consistent? 

Do you have any idea what im being asked by the second part.. 'What can you say about the ideal (f,h)?

Comment: @Mathsstudent147 As you are working on an algebraically closed field, by the Nullstellensatz $V(f,h)=\varnothing$ implies that $(f,h)=(f)+(h)=(1)$, i.e. that $(f)$ and $(h)$ are coprime.